# Add css in an if statement when I don't have access to the HTML

Tags: php, css, wordpress

So I have a dropdown menu which contains a login form. This comes from aWP plugin so I can't edit the code directly. Now once I enable said plugin it always shows on the website. I only want it to show if `is_user_logged_in` is false. The solution I came up with would be to use an if statement to check if the user is logged in or not and to show some text or the login form depending on the situation. Now this idea didn't work since the login form will always show. My question therefor would be if its possible to add some css to a class when I don't have access to the HTML? The code I came up with so far is noted below.

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    /* The logout function */
} else {
    /* The code that SHOULD change the CSS. */
}
?>
```

Now obviously I removed the logout function since it's not needed here and it makes the code look cleaner.

PS. The class we need to change would be .lorem and the styling would be display: block/none;

Comment: Please, remember that your login form would still be visible to text-only HTML clients and they would have no way of knowing if that login form should or souldn't be used.

Comment: Can you not properly hook into the plugin via a filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `.loginForm` to your class or id of your loginf form.

```
add_action('wp_head', 'my_function');

function my_function() {
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        ?>
        <style>
            .loginForm {display: none}
        </style>
        <?php
    }
}
```